# Porque será que este replace está errado?

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte função que traz uma string como número em javascript. Ela pode trazer valor float como 10.00 e int como 12. Porque ela está errada? Dá como replace is undefined na linha: `text.replace("R$","");`

```
function moneyTextToFloat(text){
  var cleanText = text.replace("R$","");
  cleanText = cleanText.replace(",",".");
  return parseFloat(cleanText);
}
```

Está aqui o código em javascript, que não foi mencionado a cima:

```
// faz o cálculo do total junto com o preço da taxa de entrega
function calculateTotalProductsEntrega()
{
  var produtos = document.getElementsByClassName("produto");
  var totalProdutos = 0;

  for(var pos = 0; pos < produtos.length; pos++)
  {

    // seleciona o preço
    var priceElements = produtos[pos].getElementsByClassName("precoproduto");
    var priceText = priceElements[0].innerHTML;
    var price = moneyTextToFloat(priceText);

    // seleciona a quantidade
    var qtyElements = produtos[pos].getElementsByClassName("quantidadeproduto");
    var qtyText = qtyElements[0].value;
    var quantity = moneyTextToFloat(qtyText);

    // pega a taxa de entrega prevista
    var shiptElements = produtos[pos].getElementsByClassName("taxaentrega");
    var shiptText = shiptElements[0].innerHTML;
    var shipt = moneyTextToFloat(shiptText);

    var subtotal = (quantity * price) + shipt;

    totalProdutos += subtotal;
  }

  return totalProdutos;
}
```

O HTML É ESSE:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como estás a chamar essa função? e essa linha `text.replace("R$","");` está assim sozinha, sem ser usada?

Comment: Não a linha de cima fala sobre o erro em si

Comment: Como estás a chamar essa função?

Comment: Bem vou colocar na resposta o javascript

Comment: Podes colocar na pergunta que nós ajudamos a formatar. Clica em [edit].

Comment: Se a variável `text` não tem o método `replace` é porque ela não é uma string. Reveja o que passa para a função.

Comment: Como já mencionado pelo @Renan se acontece isso é porque "text" não é string. Faça text.toString().replace("R$", "")

Comment: Pelo que vejo `moneyTextToFloat` vai sempre receber uma string. Podes fazer um exemplo aqui ou num jsFiddle que reproduza o problema online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Provavelmente está sendo passado algum valor que não é String, neste caso, para prevenir, converta o parâmetro text para string:

```
var cleanText = String(text).replace("R$","");
```

Assim você garante que sempre será string :)